# I am trying to change the time scale of a discrete function in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, discrete-mathematics

```
bits = [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1];
for a=1:length(bits)
if bits(a) == 1
    bit(a) = 5;
else
    bit(a) = -5;
end
end
i = 1;
t = 0:0.01:length(bits);
for b=1:length(t)
if t(b) <= i
    y(b) = bit(i);
else 
    y(b) = bit(i);
    i = i+1;
end
end
plot(t,y);
```

I am plotting y at t from 0 to 8. 
I need to change the time scale to 0 to 8us with each bit lasting 1us and a step of 10ns.
Simply changing the time scale will only plot the first value as length of array is 8. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: How about using `xlim([-1 10])` and `ylim([-6 6])` after your plot command?

Comment: this may help: https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-axis-limits-of-graph.html